# How to judge if tabbed browsing is enabled in IE using VB?

Tags: internet-explorer, vb6

I'm doing an automation job with InternetExplorer object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I can think of doing this is by checking the registry settings for Internet Explorer.

The registry setting (on Win7 IE8) is under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TabbedBrowsing\Enabled.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. That's what I've done. And if the entry doesn't exist, I suppose it's disabled (unsupported). :)